# Python: Selecting a group of numbers with regex

Tags: regex

I have several files where I am trying to extract the second group of numbers:

Length   1.2345 +- 0.765

I am trying to extract 0.765 or what the number is.

I have tried many regex combinations. I either extract 1.2345 +- 0.765 or nothing.

Any suggestions?
Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

You can find a group of numbers or . that come after a first group of numbers or .. and use regex capture groups. See regex101.com to test your regex.  For example, here's one way to find a pattern of:  no number 0 or more times, then number or decimal 1 or more times, then no number or decimal, then second number:

```
text = 'Length 1.2345 +- 0.765'
number2 = re.sub('[^0-9\.]{0,}[0-9\.]{1,}[^0-9\.]{1,}([0-9\.])', r'\1', text)
print(number2)
# 0.765
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another regex.

```
(?=[^-+])(\d*\.?\d+)$
```

1. 1st Capturing Group (\d*.?\d+)
   \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

   - matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
     ? matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
     \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])

- matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

and here is it on regex101
https://regex101.com/r/VV6prY/1

Comment: Thank you. I will look at regex 101